# In Shortcuts on iPadOS and iOS, where is the Adjust Date action?

Tags: ios, ipad, shortcuts-app, ipados

I found a way to end an event 50 minutes after I started it using Adjust Date. However I could only find Adjust Date by copying it from a shortcut I downloaded [here](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/c1dda979f4134c5cbbbec3e2638b09a2)

Where did Adjust date come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Shortcuts app, typing “Adjust” in the ‘Search for apps and actions’ box will reveal what you seek.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there a list somewhere of all available commands?

Comment: @OrigamiEye  Not that I'm aware of, but I can offer two less-than-convenient links from Apple.  (Workflow Help https://help.apple.com/workflow/#/) and (Shortcuts User Guide https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios).

Comment: I spent several minutes going through the Shortcuts app, but couldn't find a list of date operations. They seem to only be available via search. That said, an independent dev has them listed here: https://www.matthewcassinelli.com/actions/groups/apps/dates/

Comment: Good link, thank you.  Also, typing “date” in the Shortcuts search bar will reveal date-related functions.